# What is the difference between .enabled and set enabled

Tags: objective-c

for example

`uiLabel.enabled = NO;` and `[uiLabel setEnabled:NO];`

Does it affect anything in terms of compiling or performance?

Comment: Have you read the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)?

Comment: Didn't find it, i searched iOS. I guess its the same. ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference at all. As far as the compiler is concerned, the two syntaxes are identical, and they result in identical binaries. Feel free to use either syntax interchangeably.

In general, for a class `Foo` with property `bar`:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@property bar;
@end
```

the following getters are identical:

```
baz = [foo bar];
baz = foo.bar;
```

and the following setters are identical:

```
foo.bar = baz;
[foo setBar:baz];
```

The compiler makes the translations; you can use either syntax without worry.